# HP network scanning query

Tags: networking, hp

I'm having trouble getting computers (both Windows and Mac) to scan from an MFD to the computers in question.

The printer can be seen, added, and printed to from the network.  Scan to email works quite happily, and the MFD can be seen by scanning software, but when trying to use the HP Easy Scan Utility, the scanner reports an error, with no error code, and goes no further.

The affected MFD is an HP Color LaserJet MFP M577.  I've opened up the network to allow Bonjour traffic, including p2p traffic, and all the rest.  However, I'm completely baffled as to why it won't work.

I'm rather hoping it isn't because I bought the wrong model of scanner.

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 0):

It's a business model, it support scan to folder, scan to usb and scan to email. This model don't seem to support an interactive scan, please see the manual.

For a shared printer and scanner I strongly suggest to do a scan to folder instead and show to your users how to use such method. If your goal was to share a scanner it's a good model.

> This [document](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/2b/2d/2b2dc5f2-5a15-4022-a124-1d291c80fd3a.pdf) explains how to enable and configure the scan to network
>   folder function. The printer has a feature that enables it to scan a
>   document and save it to a network folder. To use this scan feature,
>   the printer must be connected to a network; however, the feature is
>   not available until it has been configured by using the HP Embedded
>   Web Server (EWS). There are two methods in the EWS for configuring
>   Scan to network folder. Use the Save to Network Folder Setup page for
>   advanced configuration, or use the Scan to Network Folder Setup Wizard
>   for basic configuration.